# Django не принимает файл в ImageField

Tags: python, django

При попытке загрузить через форму файл с изображением, джанго соответствующим образом перезагружает страницу и уведомляет о том что поле с изображением "**Обязательное поле.**" Причём если файл в поле не добавить, джанго заранее уведомляет о том что необходимо заполнить поле "добавить файл изображения".

Файл не загружается на сервер...
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема и почему так происходит, что джанго видит в форме пустое поле?

[image: Заполняем форму]
[image: Пытаемся отправить форму без изображения]
[image: Добавили файл]
[image: Отправили форму - Получили информацию о пустой строке]

Model

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Изображение')
```

View

```
def item_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = item_new_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save()
            item.save()
            return redirect('item_detail', id=item.id)
    else:
        form = item_new_form()
    return render(request, 'sportinia/items/item_new.html', {'form': form})
```

Controller

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('item/new/', views.item_new, name='item_new'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings

```
...
'django.template.context_processors.media',
...
----------

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),)
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'files', 'media')
```

Form

```
class item_new_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'category',
            'image',
            'name',
            'description',
            'price',
            'available',
        )
```

Лишние "на мой взгляд" данные убрал для большей читаемости, но при необходимости - обновлю любой участок кода т.к я новичок и мог что-то важное упустить из внимания.

Comment: `item_new_form` покажите. подозреваю, что `blank=True, null=True` может помочь справиться с данной проблемой.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Добавил форму. При blank/null форма просто игнорирует данное поле, якобы позволяя ему быть незаполненным. Моя же проблема в том, что в конечном итоге я не могу получить файл на локальном тестовом сервере, он туда по каким-то причинам не передаётся.

Comment: 1. Посмотрите, что у вас в request.FILES приходит. 2. Сколько весит изображение? 3. Как вы отрисовываете форму?

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Спасибо, проблема решена благодаря Вашему комментарию! В форме (отрисовка на странице) отсутствовал атрибут enctype, из-за чело файлы не передавались.